# Bootstrap angular responsivity issue in button group

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, jhipster, responsive, bootswatch

I m new to front end developement and I desire to be full stack, I m using Jhipster, angular and bootstrap for self study purpose.

I successfully installed a bootswatch theme (pulse), after some work I tried to create a card list to present some data.

unfortunatly my work is lacking in responsivity as seen in the picture below in tablet mode

[image: students pane]

As you see there is a lot to do and I don't have an idea what should I do to fix it all

So I m **asking about only how to fix the buttons issue in my cards** for a start, maybe this will lead me to understand and get a grasp to what to do alone to other issues (menu and filters)

below I m providing all code that I think implied on this :

**The main app template**

```
<jhi-page-ribbon></jhi-page-ribbon>
<div>
    <router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid mt-4">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
</div>
```

**The cards code snippet in my candidat template**

1 **global template : all code**

```
<div>
    <h2 id="page-heading">
        <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.home.title">Candidats</span>
        <button id="jh-create-entity" class="btn btn-primary float-right jh-create-entity create-candidat"
            [routerLink]="['/candidat/new']">
            <fa-icon [icon]="'plus'"></fa-icon>
            <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.home.createLabel">
                Create new Candidat
            </span>
        </button>
    </h2>
    <jhi-alert></jhi-alert>
    <br />
    <div jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="reverse" [callback]="transition.bind(this)">
        <div class="row mb-4 ml-1">
            <input type="search" class="form-control col-sm-8 " autocomplete="off" placeholder="{{'autoEcoleV01App.constants.search' | translate}}"
                [(ngModel)]="searchValue" />
            <div class="btn-group col-sm-4">
                <button class="btn btn-sm float-left btn-outline-secondary col" jhiSortBy="nom">
                    <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.nom">Nom</span>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm float-left btn-outline-secondary col" jhiSortBy="prenom">
                    <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.prenom">Prenom</span>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm float-left btn-outline-secondary col" jhiSortBy="nid">
                    <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.nid">Nid</span>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div *ngFor="let candidat of (candidats | filterBy: ['nom','prenom','mere','pere','telephone','nid']: searchValue) ;trackBy: trackId"
                class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
                <div class="card card-focusable" style="min-height: 100%;">
                    <a *ngIf="candidat.photo" (click)="openFile(candidat.photoContentType, candidat.photo)">
                        <img [src]="'data:' + candidat.photoContentType + ';base64,' + candidat.photo"
                            style="max-height: 360px;  max-width: 100%;"
                            class="card-img-top " alt="candidat image" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="card-body ">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{candidat.nom}} {{candidat.prenom}}</h4>
                        <p class="card-text ml-1">
                            <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.dateInscription">Date Inscription  </span>: {{candidat.dateInscription | date:'mediumDate'}}
                            <br >
                            <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.telephone">Téléphone  </span>: {{candidat.telephone}}
                         </p>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <div class="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
                                <button type="submit" [routerLink]="['/candidat', candidat.id, 'view' ]"
                                    class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                                    <fa-icon [icon]="'eye'"></fa-icon>
                                    <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.view">View</span>
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" [routerLink]="['/candidat', candidat.id, 'edit']"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                    <fa-icon [icon]="'pencil-alt'"></fa-icon>
                                    <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.edit">Edit</span>
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit"
                                    [routerLink]="['/', 'candidat', { outlets: { popup: candidat.id + '/delete'} }]"
                                    replaceUrl="true" queryParamsHandling="merge" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                    <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
                                    <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.delete">Delete</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

2 **Only card code for easy reading**

```
<div class="card-body ">
   <h4 class="card-title">{{candidat.nom}} {{candidat.prenom}}</h4>
   <p class="card-text ml-1">
      <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.dateInscription">Date Inscription  </span>: {{candidat.dateInscription | date:'mediumDate'}}
      <br >
      <span jhiTranslate="autoEcoleV01App.candidat.telephone">Téléphone  </span>: {{candidat.telephone}}
   </p>
   <div class="text-right">
      <div class="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
         <button type="submit" [routerLink]="['/candidat', candidat.id, 'view' ]"
            class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
            <fa-icon [icon]="'eye'"></fa-icon>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.view">View</span>
         </button>
         <button type="submit" [routerLink]="['/candidat', candidat.id, 'edit']"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <fa-icon [icon]="'pencil-alt'"></fa-icon>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.edit">Edit</span>
         </button>
         <button type="submit"
            [routerLink]="['/', 'candidat', { outlets: { popup: candidat.id + '/delete'} }]"
            replaceUrl="true" queryParamsHandling="merge" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
            <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.delete">Delete</span>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't thin a button group can be made responsive by, for example, displaying the buttons vertically instead of horizontally. So, if you want to keep using button groups, you should make sure you have enough horizontal space, i.e. display less than 4 candidate cards per row, so that each candidate car has more horizontal space.

Comment: thanks you gived me the great Idea I will change the class depending on the screen size this way i will make enought space for buttons :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JB Nizet comment I was made in the stright path so I searched for a way to be sure that there is enought space, my answer was **Breakpoints**

Here is what I have done :

- I used [angular material](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api) and [this tutorial was helpfull](https://alligator.io/angular/breakpoints-angular-cdk/)
- setup a goal : I have to change cards number depending on screen size

Here is my implementation of the solution

**Importing the module in my global app module `app.module.ts` to be used in all components**

```
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
@NgModule({
    imports: [...
              LayoutModule,
              ...])
```

**using the `BreakpointService` in my `candidat.component.ts`**

```
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-candidat',
    templateUrl: './candidat.component.html'
})
export class CandidatComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  someVars: any;
  small: any;
  medium: any;
  large: any;

  constructor(
    protected someServices: MyServices,
    public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someLogic();
    this.breakpointObserver
            .observe(['(max-width: 425px)'])
            .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
                if (state.matches) {
                    this.small = true;
                    this.medium = false;
                    this.large = false;
                }
                console.log('Small screen event');
            });
    this.breakpointObserver
            .observe(['(max-width: 1025px)', '(min-width: 426px)'])
            .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
                if (state.matches) {
                    this.small = false;
                    this.medium = true;
                    this.large = false;
                }
                console.log('Medium screen event');
            });
    this.breakpointObserver
            .observe(['(min-width: 1025px)'])
            .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
                if (state.matches) {
                    this.small = false;
                    this.medium = false;
                    this.large = true;
                }
                console.log('Large screen event');
            });
    }

    cardsStyleClasses() {
        return {
            'mb-4': true,
            'col-sm-1': this.small,
            'col-sm-4': this.medium,
            'col-sm-3': this.large
        };
    }
}
```

**finally using `ngClass` in my templte**

```
[ngClass]="cardsStyleClasses()"
```

Comment: In the next weeks I will try to make this better by providing an observable boolean vars that refer to small medium large screen, this all provided by a service so this way my component code stays ligth